# Database indexing: how to best index items with names and categories?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, performance, indexing

I have a postgres database that has ~100,000 rows and many (~60) columns. The columns of interest are `name` and `category`, both of which are varchars.

```
create table items
(
    id uuid,
    name varchar(256),
    category varchar(256),
    data varchar(256)[],
    ...
)
```

My application frequently makes the following queries

1. `select * from items where name = 'name';`
2. `select * from items where category = 'category';`
3. `select * from items where name = 'name' and category = 'category';`
4. `select * from items where id = 'id';

And less commonly

5. `select * from items where 'data' = ANY(data);`

What is the best way to index this data to maximize efficiency? Should I have single index on both columns, and if so, in which order?

Neither the `name` nor `category` column is guaranteed to be unique. I estimate ~1000 categories and ~40,000 unique names.

Comment: Those aren't the only queries. I also query by id and sometimes with additional comparisons in the where clause. These are just the most commonly used columns.

Comment: Please show more common queries.

Comment: Slightly off topic, using arrays is mostly not the most efficient way to store, search and extract data. Are you sure about this data model?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are going to need separate indexes here. Query 1 cannot use an index leading by `category`, and query 2 cannot use one leading by `name`. Likewise for query 5.

Query 3 needs a multi-column index. The only question remaining is which of them to add the extra column to. Look at whichever column is more selective, in this case it's `name`.

Query 4 can use the primary key index. `id` should be declared a primary key, assuming that's what it is.

Query 5 would need another index on `data`. I believe this must be a GIN index, also you might need to change `ANY` to `@>`.

So you have three separate indexes.

```sql
(name, category)
(category)
(data)  -- needs to be a GIN index.
```

Sixty columns is very wide (probably too wide and a sign of poor normalization), and you are also doing `select *` so key lookups are inevitable. Therefore there is no point using `INCLUDE` columns.

---

All of this only applies if these are the only queries being executed. Otherwise further analysis is needed: maybe you need `INCLUDE` columns, or other columns can be added to the keys.

Comment: These aren't the only queries that could be called, though they are probably >90% of all queries. ID is my primary key, I just have it marked at the bottom of the create table statement and did not include it in the question.

Also, could you explain the difference between `ANY` and `@>`? I thought they achieved the same thing.

Comment: Query 3 can also use single-column indexes.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe True but then you get an index union, which is less efficient. You anyway have an index on one of the columns, you might as well add the other column in.

Comment: @jnasworld223 Not so experienced with Postgres, but maybe check this out https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/187963/220697

Comment: If one of the conditions is already selective, an index on that column is enough to support the query with two `WHERE` conditions.

Comment: Perhaps. I suppose in this case there would be on average only 2 or 3 rows read.